# How do I import some other JS file into my IIFE wrapped file

Tags: javascript

This is my IIFE wrapped file named `iframe-loader.js`
and I want to import a state variable from other file named `store.js`. how can I achieve that.

```
  (() => {
    
    const script = document.currentScript;

    const loadWidget = () => {

        const widget = document.createElement("div");

        const widgetStyle = widget.style;
        widgetStyle.display = "none";
        widgetStyle.boxSizing = "border-box";
        widgetStyle.width = "80vw";
        widgetStyle.height = "800px";
        widgetStyle.position = "absolute";
        widgetStyle.bottom = "20px";
        widgetStyle.right = "40px";
        widgetStyle.borderTopRightRadius = "50%";
        widgetStyle.borderTopLeftRadius = "50%";
        widgetStyle.borderBottomLeftRadius = "50%";
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIFE is an Immediately invoked function expression, so you can define the function inside to takes params like this:

```
((dataFromStore) => {
 console.log(dataFromStore)
})('foo')
```

Comment: The question is asking about getting the value `'foo'` from a variable defined in another file. This doesn't seem to address that at all.

Comment: He stated that he need a variable from the other file, so I assumed that he has the value before IIFE.

Comment: If you're working from that assumption, then you've over complicating things. The variable is accessible inside the function anyway. You don't need to use an argument to create a new variable and copy the value to it.

Answer (score 0):

If *store.js* is not a module and declares that variable as a global, then you can just read the global value.

If *store.js* is a module and explicitly exports that variable, then you can `import` it (but then *iframe-loader.js* has to be a module, which it presumably isn't since you are using an IIFE).

---

Rewriting both files as modules is probably a good idea (unless you need to support obsolete browsers) as it makes managing code and exchanging variables clearer. [MDN has a good guide to modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Answer (score 0):

JS has come a long way, we first had browserify and now the ES6 modules. For that reason, if you can, you might try to convert your iifes to modules using export/import and adding the `type="module"` attribute.

However, if you can't for whatever reason, I used to work with (and I still use) a module system  years ago that relied on async execution of iifes, and the parameters would be passed by parsing `function.toString`. You can try it [here](https://github.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/taskq) and read about it [here](https://medium.com/@ibowankenobi/pausing-resuming-browser-app-logic-using-taskq-js-884ec5a8ce86)

In your case it would look like:

```
(()=>{
     const loadWidget = (someParamFromStormJS) => {
         ...
         taskq.export(someParam,"someParamFromLoadWidget")
     }
     loadWidget._taskqId = "loadWidget";
     loadWidget._taskqWaitFor(["StormJS",...]);
     taskq.push(loadWidget)

})()
```

Similarly in StormJS you would do:

```
(()=>{
      const stormJS= () => {
          ...
          taskq.export({a: 1, b: 2},"someParamFromStormJS")
      }
      stormJS._taskqId = "StormJS";
      stormJS._taskqWaitFor([]);
      taskq.push(stormJS)
})()
```

And finally in your HTML you would do:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ibowankenobi/taskq/taskq.js"></script>
<script src="./loadWidget.js" async></script>
<script src="./storm.js" async></script>
```

Note the `async` attributes.